# Why does my code output differently from what I expected in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning Java.  The following program is supposed to examine a number and determine how many factors (even divisors) that number has.  For instance,

1 has only itself as a factor.
5 has 3 factors: 1 and 5.
9 has 3 factors: 1, 3, and 9.

I supply the program with those three numbers in a list.  I expect the output to be

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

However, what I get is the original number printed that many times:

```
{1, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9}
```

What did I do wrong?

```
int totalFactor(int[] n){
    int tally =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){ 
        for(int j = 1; j <= n[i]; j++){
            if((n[i] % j) == 0){
                tally++;
            }
        }
    }
    return tally;
}

int[] factorsOfEach(int[] num){
    int[] factor = new int[totalFactor(num)];
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        for(int j = 1;j <= num[i]; j++){
            if(num[i] % j == 0){
                factor[count] = num[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return factor;
}
```

Comment: There are so many compile errors on your code. In `factorsOfEach()`, `final` is a [Java reserved keyword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)) so you can't use it as variable name. you passed `int[] num` as parameter yet you are using `list`.

Comment: If you want the output to be `int[] x = {1,5,9} factorsOfEach(x) = {1,2,3}`. You can use `System.out.print("int[] x = {1,5,9} \n\n factorsOfEach(x) = {1,2,3}");`... I'm guessing you want it to be more dynamic than that, so you probably want to specify what the code actually is meant to do.

Comment: Edited, was renaming the num.

Comment: Tightened wording and made the explanation flow better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the middle of your inner loop.  What you actually do is, every time you find a factor, you append the original number to the end of the list.

Instead, you should simply keep that count.  When you've found all the factors, just append the *count* once to the end of the list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){  // for each number in input list
    count = 0         // haven't found any factors yet for this number
    for(int j = 1; j <= num[i]; j++){  // for each potential factor
        if(num[i] % j == 0){
            count++;  // found one more factor
        }
    } // done with that potential factor
    factor[i] = count;
} // done with that number in the input list
return factor;
```